# How to scroll horizontally in Terminal Emulator for Android

Tags: shell, terminal, emulators

When I'm using [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator) (also available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), long commands frequently scroll horizontally off the window.

I feel quite dense, but I can't find a way to quickly scroll left and right to see what I typed.  I also can't find a way to enable wrapping to just wrap content within the window.

How do you do these things?

I've read [the FAQ](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), and don't see anything mentioned.

Comment: Do you have `bash` or `ash` shell? If yes, consider a switch to them. Both of them would have a configuration to auto wrap the content so you need not to worry about scrolling. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQYK.png

Comment: You could use a different terminal emulator app, there are dozens out there

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury That's certainly an option.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26818/terminal-emulator-for-android-with-specific-features